# Xcode not letting me change navigation bar font?

Tags: xcode, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to change the font family as well as the size of my navigation bar's text. However, when I select the "Title Font" button in Xcode the "Family" selector seems to be greyed out and uneselectable:

[image: navbar]

Am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: any luck with this?

Comment: @Miknash  yes, was able to do it through the storyboard

Comment: Can you post it for future similar issues?

Answer (score 0):

I am doing this through code:

```
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Avenir LT Std", size: 16)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.white]
```

I was able to set it through storyboard somehow, but it wasn't working at all.